# Return values from Dictionary key

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I'm a bit of a vb.net noob - apologies if this is a silly question.

I have a collection named Applications and these store objects of type application.

```
Dim Applications As New Dictionary(Of String, Application)()
```

Each application is created and added to this collection using

```
Public Sub New(dbid As String, name As String, status As String, mode As String)
        csv_dbid = dbid
        csv_app = name
        csv_status = status
        csv_mode = mode
    End Sub
```

See the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDzoS.png) i've included which shows in the debug/output my collection created with the objects and values associated.

I want to know a way I can access a Key and return all the corresponding values of csv_dbid, csv_app, csv_status and csv_mode. I've been googling for a bit and struggling.

Many thanks in advance.
Gary Waddell

Comment: You can retrieve the Application object with a matching key from the dictionary by using the dictionary's Item property and supplying the key.

Comment: `Applications("100").csv_dbid` etc. It looks like a Property of `Application` and the Dictionary Key are strings while represent Integers. `Application` is not exactly a great name.

Comment: Legend - thank you both Honeyboy & Jimi.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the posted screenshot you would do:

```
Dim app = Applications("100")
```

`app` Will be a HealthCareApplication like any other so you can just use it as you would:

```
app.csv_dbid = "123"
```

You can also just refer to the dictionary item without a variable:

```
Applications("100").csv_dbid = "123"
```

To find out if the dictionary knows of a key, use the ContainsKey method. This can be particularly useful if you're iterating a colection and want to handle duplicates:

```
For Each thing in someList

  if Applications.ContainsKey(thing.Key) Then
    HandleDuplicate(thing)
  Else 
    Applications(thing.Key) = New HealthCareApplication
  End if

  'It certainly exists in the collection now and this won't crash with KeyNotFound
  Applications(thing.Key).csv_dbid = thing.DbId

Next thing
```

If you enumerate a dictionary you get a collection of KeyValuePair, the Key is (in this case) the "100" you used as the indexer. The Value is a HealthCareApplication type

```
For Each kvp in Applications

  console.Write(kvp.Key)

  Console.Write(kvp.Value.csv_dbid)

Next kvp
```